# Boot from USB with Lenovo G710

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, lenovo-laptop, liveusb

What I wish to achieve: Have Debian linux on a USB stick and boot from that without touching my HD.

Problem: Can't boot from USB.

I put the Debian Live distribution on a USB stick using unetbootin and rebooted with the USB stick inserted. The latop booted into windows.

I restarted and had a rummage around in the BIOS, "boot from USB" is enabled, that appears to be the only USB related option in the entire BIOS settings.

The boot menu only gives options for boot from HD or some network related things. Choosing the HD boot option of course boots into windows.

I have fiddled with various settings in the BIOS like disabled UEFI and secure boot, but no matter what options I choose it always boots into Windows and never gives me an option to boot from USB.

Strangely there are no options to boot from CD/DVD either, but I haven't tried with a disc in the drive. Not that I care since I don't wish to boot from a DVD.

Anybody have any ideas what I should try next?

Comment: Have you tried to access the BIOS with the USB drive plugged in? It may be enumerated by the BIOS and be listed as a boot drive option then.

Comment: I tried both with and without the USB stick plugged in.

Comment: I should also add that the contents of the USB stick seem OK, I can view it in Windows, it has folders such as ".disk", "dists", "firmware", "install", "isolinux" etc.

Comment: What is the file system of the USB stick? (Right click in My Computer > Properties)

Comment: The file system is FAT32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the boot mode to legacy. Then the DVD & USB boot modes will be available to choose from in the boot loader.

Comment: This did the trick. I also had to switch the boot order from "UEFI" to "legacy". After I restarted and went back to the BIOS settings the USB stick and DVD drive were listed as bootable devices. I thank you for the answer, and I thank everyone for helping.